# Custom sent folder outlook c#

Tags: c#, outlook, vsto, outlook-addin

Im trying to save mail in custom folder but get the following eror in c#:

CS1955  Non-invocable member 'MAPIFolder.Folders' cannot be used like a method

```
Outlook.MAPIFolder inbox =
this.Application.ActiveExplorer().Session.GetDefaultFolder
(Outlook.OlDefaultFolders.olFolderInbox);

Outlook.MailItem mailItem = (Item as Outlook.MailItem);

mailItem.SaveSentMessageFolder = inbox.Folders("Test");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Outlook.MAPIFolder inbox =
this.Application.ActiveExplorer().Session.GetDefaultFolder
(Outlook.OlDefaultFolders.olFolderInbox);

Outlook.MailItem mailItem = (Item as Outlook.MailItem);

mailItem.SaveSentMessageFolder = inbox.Folders["Test"];
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, it is better to explain how to solve the problem and provide the code as an example or reference. Code-only answers can be confusing and lack context.

Comment: @RobertColumbia It is the OP that answered his/her own Q. It is not necessary the OP knows why the new solution works but still took the time to write down the answer. Kudos to OP for investing the time.